# How to obtain current-voltage trace using a picoammeter?

Tags: signal, current-measurement, oscilloscope, electrical, instrumentation

I am designing a probe where ions will finally impinge a metallic collector. The collector is connected to a picoammeter to measure the collected current. How can I finally obtain a current-voltage trace? Can I connect the picoammeter directly to an Oscilloscope which will store the signal and analyse it by a computer? Or can I directly connect the picoammeter to the computer using GPBI cable?

Comment: There is no generic picoammeter.

Comment: Yeah... you should probably let us know which picoammeter you're using (or which ones you're considering).

Comment: Well I still don't know depending on what I should chose my picoammeter. But Iwould for the moment consider this one: Keithley 486

Comment: Why no link to the datasheet for the Keithley 486?

Answer (score 0):

My old Keithley picoammeter had a 'recorder' output (analog) that
could be sent to a motorized chart recorder.   An X-Y recorder
(or the A/D converter/computer/printer equivalent) with
test voltage sensed by the 'X' channel can do the same.

Your chosen
device[Keithley 486 (see Fig 3-14)](https://www.tek.com/manual/model-486-picoammeter-and-model-487-picoammeter-voltage-source-instruction-manual-rev-d-manua) has analog outputs,  but also autoswitches
the gain.   You'll have to note the gain range, and maybe
disable gain-switching.

With suitable digital hardware (to address the IEEE-488 port)
you might skip the analog output connection, but be aware that not all
digital outputs are timely (and you want to ensure somehow
that your V and I signals don't get different delays).